# SES listContacts: The request signature we calculated does not match

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I am using the Java SDK 2 (version 2.17.51), and when attempting a simple [`listContacts`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sesv2/SesV2Client.html#listContacts--) request, I get the following:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2.model.SesV2Exception: 
The request signature we calculated does not match the 
signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key 
and signing method. Consult the service documentation for 
details.
```

This same key works fine when calling [`getContact`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sesv2/SesV2Client.html#getContact-java.util.function.Consumer-), and is also  used with other modules (e.g. S3) without problems, and the associated user has "Full Access" for SES. If I just remove the credentials, I get a different error (`software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from any of the providers`) so finding the credentials doesn't seem to be the issue.

EDIT: adding the code (Scala)

```scala
    val client = sesv2.SesV2Client.builder()
      .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
      .build()

    val topic =
      TopicFilter.builder()
        .topicName("mytopic")
        .build()

    val filter =
      ListContactsFilter.builder()
        .topicFilter(topic)
        .build()

    val request = 
      ListContactsRequest.builder()
        .contactListName("mylist")
        .pageSize(10000)
        .filter(filter)
        .build()

    val contacts = client.listContacts(request).contacts
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @smac2020 updated. It's plain scala code, no fancy implicits or anything

Comment: @mitchus did you ever solve this? Having the exact same issue. Created a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73059306/how-to-fix-aws-403-error-check-your-aws-secret-access-key-and-signing-method-w. Would greatly appreciate a solution if you found one!

Comment: @After_Sunset no, I had an open ticket with aws support for months, but it never got solved.

Comment: @mitchus got it thank u for reply. I also opened a ticket. Thats pretty sad, this seems like critical functionality. I know it is for me at least.

Comment: How did you end up going about listing out your contacts?

Comment: @After_Sunset If I remember correctly, I used the async version instead, which did not suffer from this issue