# How to fix AWS 403 error "Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method" when calling SES listcontacts

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses, aws-java-sdk

I have been stuck for about the past 6 hours at this point I'm thinking the only reasonable explanations are that this is a AWS SDK bug or the error message is wrong.

I am using SESv2 class from the AWS SDK in a JAVA SpringBoot app and attempting to manage various details of my SES (Simple Email Service) account.

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2.SesV2Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2.model.*;
```

I have created an IAM user, created security credentials, set them up using multiple different methods as described here [guid to credentials environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_environment.html) I've given full access to SES to this IAM role user. I then wrote some code and I was able to do all of the following,

- Create a contact list
- Delete a contact list
- Create contact
- Create a Topic in a contact list
- Send an email

However, for some unknown reason when I go to test a function I wrote to get a list of contacts so I can test sending an email to multiple contacts I get the following 403 error message,

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
> provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult
> the service documentation for details.

I've verified the credentials are correct. I have created a new set of credentials and made the old set inactive. No dice, all the functions listed above still work however the `listContacts` in the `SesV2Client` class still fails with the same error. As you can see below I even bypassed the env variables  and just hardcoded the key and secret to pull out all the stops, still fails. In the function that fails, I've gone over and over the values im passing in they are valid and exist 100% because as I said I can make the other calls in the list above to verify the topics and contact list exists.

```
private List<Contact> listContactsForSiteUpdatesMailingList() {
try (SesV2Client client = SesV2Client.builder()
            .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
            .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds))
            .build()){

        TopicFilter topicFilter = TopicFilter.builder().topicName(TOPIC_SITE_UPDATES).useDefaultIfPreferenceUnavailable(true).build();
        ListContactsFilter listContactsFilter = ListContactsFilter.builder().topicFilter(topicFilter).filteredStatus(SubscriptionStatus.OPT_IN).build();
        ListContactsRequest listContactsRequest = ListContactsRequest.builder()
                .contactListName(CONTACT_LIST).filter(listContactsFilter).build();

        ListContactsResponse listContactsResponse = client.listContacts(listContactsRequest);

        return listContactsResponse.contacts();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("The email was not sent. Error message: "
                + ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Whats going on here and how can I get to the bottom of this error?

EDIT:
Looking at AWS Console Users>Access Management and then looking at the user a created I can even verify that there was "programmatic access" [image]

An example of accessing a ContactList with no issues[image]

EDIT 2: My SES account is currently sandboxed. I just wanted to mention the question is this possibly happening because of that? Grasping at straws here.

Comment: I will test this method and report back. In my original answer (that i removed) - i showed listEmailIdentities.

Comment: Sounds good, thank you much appreciated. FYI, I did add in .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create()) and setup env variables per the java guide still got the same error.

Comment: I will see if i can reproduce. I will let you know tomorrow. I will code this method 1st thing in the morning.

Comment: See my new response.

Comment: I have created an issue ticket here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/2812

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your issue. I created a list and added a contact. Both worked. However, when i executed **listContacts**, I got this error:

[image]

This looks like a bug. To address this, open a Github issue on the SDK Java Github here:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java

Comment: hmm i see I was looking at the wrong guide however I hardcoded the creds in so I'm doubtful this will help let me see though. Also, all the other calls listed work fine.

Comment: See my update answer

Comment: Interesting I will look into opening an issue tomorrow. If you get a chance see me edit 2 above.

Comment: I will talk to SDK team tomorrow - but this call should work like the others

Comment: Sounds good, sorry just getting back to this now. Do you still recommend creating a new issue on the aws-sdk git page?

Answer (score 0):

This is confirmed as a bug in the AWS SDK. To get around this you can use the async client like so

```
 SesV2AsyncClient client = SesV2AsyncClient.builder()
                    .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                    .build())
        TopicFilter topicFilter = TopicFilter.builder().topicName(TOPIC_SITE_UPDATES).useDefaultIfPreferenceUnavailable(true).build();
        ListContactsFilter listContactsFilter = ListContactsFilter.builder().topicFilter(topicFilter).filteredStatus(SubscriptionStatus.OPT_IN).build();
        ListContactsRequest listContactsRequest = ListContactsRequest.builder()
                .contactListName(CONTACT_LIST).filter(listContactsFilter).build();

        CompletableFuture<ListContactsResponse> listContactsResponseCompletableFuture = client.listContacts(listContactsRequest);
        ListContactsResponse listContactsResponse = listContactsResponseCompletableFuture.get();
```